# Loop through arrays with limitations

Tags: php, loops

I have an array of transports:

```
$transports = [
  0 => ['label' => 'Transport 1', 'maxPalettesToLoad' => 5],
  1 => ['label' => 'Transport 2', 'maxPalettesToLoad' => 2]
];
```

and an array of palettes with certain products i want to "load" on the transport above

```
$palettes = [
  0 => ['id_product' => 2, 'id_sale_order_item' => 1, 'amount' => 4],
  1 => ['id_product' => 4, 'id_sale_order_item' => 4, 'amount' => 3]
];
```

What I'm struggling to accomplish is to load all the palettes onto transports where total number of loaded palettes is equal to `maxPalettesToLoad` parameter of each transport. I'm looking for a solution that will generate me values like:

```
$toret = [
  'Transport 1' => [
       0 => ['id_product' => 2, 'id_sale_order_item' => 1],
       1 => ['id_product' => 2, 'id_sale_order_item' => 1],
       2 => ['id_product' => 2, 'id_sale_order_item' => 1],
       3 => ['id_product' => 2, 'id_sale_order_item' => 1],
       4 => ['id_product' => 4, 'id_sale_order_item' => 4]
  ],
  'Transport 2' => [
       0 => ['id_product' => 4, 'id_sale_order_item' => 4],
       1 => ['id_product' => 4, 'id_sale_order_item' => 4]
  ],
];
```

EDIT: Here is my attempt. It's kinda different in terms of data structure, because I simplified it to make it shorted

```
                foreach ($transportsData as $transportData) {

                    $modelTransportOrder = new TransportOrder();
                    $modelTransportOrder->max_palettes_amount = $maxPalettesAmount;
                    $status &= $modelTransportOrder->save();

                    $amountAssigned = $transportData['palletes'];

                    if ($status) {
                        $j = 1;

                        foreach ($palettesData as $paletteData) {
                            if ($modelSaleOrderItem = SaleOrderItem::findOne([$paletteData['id_sale_order_item']])) {

                                for ($i = 0; $i < $paletteData['amount']; $i++) {

                                    if ($j <= $amountAssigned) {
                                        $modelTransportOrderItem = new TransportOrderItem();
                                        $modelTransportOrderItem->id_transport_order = $modelTransportOrder->id;
                                        $modelTransportOrderItem->id_product = $modelSaleOrderItem->id_product;
                                        $modelTransportOrderItem->id_sale_order_item = $modelSaleOrderItem->id;
                                        $modelTransportOrderItem->index = $j;
                                        $status &= $modelTransportOrderItem->save();

                                        // Index reset
                                        if ($j == $amountAssigned) {
                                            $j = 0;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    $j++;
                                }

                            } else {
                                $status = false;
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        // Zapis transportu nie powiódł się
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's just a set of `foreach` loops and condiiton inside.

Comment: What is the actual issue here? You can simply go, iterate over the transports and put as many palettes onto it as the transport's max value allows...

Comment: Show us your best attempt (code) you might be closer to a solution than you think.

Comment: I added my attempt into main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem using `unset` after each used palette:

```
                        foreach ($initedPalettes as $key => $palette) {
                            if ($i <= $amountAssigned) {
                                $modelsTransportOrderItem = self::createTransportOrderItem
                                (
                                    $modelTransportOrder->id,
                                    $palette['idProduct'],
                                    $palette['idSaleOrderItem'],
                                    $i
                                );
                                $status &= $modelsTransportOrderItem->save();

                                unset($initedPalettes[$key]);

                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
```